# [Navigation stack] self defined Actionlib or move_base?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a crucial question about the realization of a navigation for my robot model. The robot is already moving very well and as expected in a simulative environment (RViz). Given a target point, it is able to calculate the desired trajectory and moves to the point autonomously.

One drawback in my design is: I have implemented everything on my own and since the dynamic model was really difficult to realize and I never did use the `move_base` [package](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) or something like that. In my code reads the controller ***points*** and not ***velocities*** commands (like the output of `move_base`, which is `/cmd_vel` )
Now I want to implement a navigation stack for my robot but I m a little bit confused about which way should I consider:

1. **Option:** I could take inspiration from the tutorials about `move_base` and leave it putting out velocities commands which I ll later feed into my robot's model.
   **Pro:** exaustive tutorials about move_base on this website and lot of explanations. **Contra:** my robot reads goals defined as **points** and moves accordingly to reach them. Feeding velocities commands instead of positions will not work.
2. **Option:** I feed the goal's position into the model and write an actionlib (server + client) to track the progress to the goals. At the goal it will trigger to the next goal. **Pro:** it sounds much easier and logic than the above idea. **Contra:** no idea on how to start developing such a server/client application and mostly important I could not use implement something like the base_local_planner if I need to generate a simple map to avoid obstacles (till now not necessary).

**UPDATE #1:**
The controller reads the published points (goals) respect to the `/odom` frame and the controller drive the robot there. Since fthe only transformation is between `/odom` and `/frame_link` I made the assumption that goals are "fixed" respect to the world (in RViz). Later I m going to publish them respect to `/map`.

I hoe my question is clear enough. It not I will update it!

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193867/%5Bnavigation-stack%5D-self-defined-actionlib-or-move_base?/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-30**:
So the robot controller takes in points? In what reference frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you partially replicated the functionality of `move_base` - specifically the goal-to-trajectory part. However, in a navigation context, the usefulness of this part is somewhat limited without processing the additional data you need for obstacle avoidance (costmaps for `move_base`).

As David suggests, you can pipe the output path of local planner into your trajectory generator, however you'll have a lot of wasted cycles there - the path is created because the local planner has already evaluated sensory data, generated the trajectories, and calculated the endpoints for the paths (someone correct me if I'm wrong). So you'll be doing the same work twice.

While it's really going to hurt, I'd suggest stripping out the trajectory generation, and accepting `cmd_vel` input instead. It's a learning experience to try to use the tools available and not reinvent the wheel :) Besides, the ROS way would have been to develop these parts as seperate modules in the first place, so that you could connect your robot's driver (which accepts `cmd_vel` and outputs `odom`) to any number of navigation implementations.

---

Also, I know nothing about your robot. If your trajectory generator is very well suited to your system, and performs better than the two already implemented in the navigation stack, you should totally rewrite it to use the `base_local_planner` interface (processing costmap data and outputing velocity commands), taking advantage of the infrastructure provided by `move_base` as a state machine, and publish it to contribute back to the ROS ecosystem!

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/20692/marco/) on 2014-11-04**:
Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The local planner usually also publishes its plan as a Path. Could you use the points in that as input to your robot"?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-03**:
Do you mean: `~<name>/local_plan` ?
OK I will try...